Search node in model tree in forge viewer
I could not find an example of how we can filter the model tree in the forge viewer, meaning that If I pass an node, I get all the tree path to it.
In the documentation I've found some example for getting the specif node, but not its path.
Any examples of this implementation ?

The built-in model browser in the viewer has a search functionality that will list all nodes (and their paths in the tree) based on your search phrase:

If you want to find the path for any given node programatically, you could use something like this:
function getObjectTreePath(model, dbid) {
    const tree = model.getInstanceTree();
    let path = [tree.getNodeName(dbid)];
    while (tree.getNodeParentId(dbid)) {
        dbid = tree.getNodeParentId(dbid);
        path.unshift(tree.getNodeName(dbid));
    }
    return path;
}

